# Merge Firestore streams using rxDart

Tags: firebase, stream, dart, flutter, rxdart

I am trying to merge two streams from Firestore into one stream using RxDart, but it's only returning results of one stream

```
Stream getData() {
    Stream stream1 = Firestore.instance.collection('test').where('type', isEqualTo: 'type1').snapshots();
    Stream stream2 = Firestore.instance.collection('test').where('type', isEqualTo: 'type2').snapshots();
    return Observable.merge(([stream2, stream1]));
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `combineLatest` instead.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930918/update-streams-based-on-filters-in-dart-flutter/51931169#51931169

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you might not need RxDart to do this.
If you just want to have two Firestore streams merged to one Dart `Stream` you can use `StreamZip` from the `dart:async` package.

```
import 'dart:async';     

Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> getData() {
  Stream stream1 = Firestore.instance.collection('test').where('type', isEqualTo: 'type1').snapshots();
  Stream stream2 = Firestore.instance.collection('test').where('type', isEqualTo: 'type2').snapshots();
  return StreamZip([stream1, stream2]).asBroadcastStream();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use mergeWith to get one Stream from two seperate streams using RxDart like below,

```
 Stream getData() {
    Stream stream1 = Firestore.instance.collection('test').where('type', isEqualTo: 'type1').snapshots();
    Stream stream2 = Firestore.instance.collection('test').where('type', isEqualTo: 'type2').snapshots();
    return stream1.mergeWith([stream2]);
  }
```

Comment: please how can i then access this data