# Reading two streams from Cloud Firestore and merging the streams

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want  to read data from my cloud firestore DB with the logical OR operator.I have read some other posts on doing it with `Stream` merge as in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238875/merge-firestore-streams-using-rxdart) but it still doesnt seem to do the trick as it just returns just one Stream and an Error. I want to use the data returned in a `StreamBuilder`
.   so far I have tried this

```
Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> getData() {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream1 = Firestore.instance.collection('htTwo').document('users')
        .collection('userdata').document('all_').collection('personal_').where('myUID', isEqualTo: 'yrUID').snapshots();

      Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream2 = Firestore.instance.collection('htTwo').document('users')
            .collection('userdata').document('all_').collection('personal_').where('othersUID', isEqualTo: 'some123Giberish').snapshots();
      return StreamZip([stream1, stream2]).asBroadcastStream();
    }
```

//In the StreamBuilder ...

```
StreamBuilder(
         stream: getData(),
         builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>>snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData )return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: Theme(
                data:theme.copyWith(
                   accentColor: Colors.red,
                   inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme()),
                child:Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator() ,)
              ),
              );

                  int lengthOfDocs=0;
                  int querySnapShotCounter = 0;
                  snapshot.data.forEach((snap){lengthOfDocs = lengthOfDocs + snap.documents.length;});    
                  int counter = 0;



                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: lengthOfDocs,
                    itemBuilder: (_,int index){
                      try{DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data[querySnapShotCounter].documents[counter];
                      counter = counter + 1 ;
                       return new Container(
                         child:ListTile(
               title: Text(doc.data["othersUID"]),
               subtitle: Text("${doc.data["myUID"]} :"),
             ) 
                         );
                      }
                      catch(RangeError){
                        querySnapShotCounter = querySnapShotCounter+1;
                        counter = 0;
                        DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data[querySnapShotCounter].documents[counter];
                        counter = counter + 1 ;
                         return new Container(child: Text(doc.data["othersUID"]));
                      }

                    },
                  );

         },
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

> //error
>
> I/flutter ( 3939): The following RangeError was thrown building:
>
> I/flutter ( 3939): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2

Comment: inside where there are some option you can use 
```where('date_and_time', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '12.22')```

Comment: yes, but in my case am not comparing numbers