# Combine streams with rxdart to be used in a single StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

For several days I tried to find an answer for this question.
Many examples are confusing for me, and I really don't understand how to implement them using rxdart, despite they look so simple.

I'm trying to combine 4 collections from Firestore to be used in a single StreamBuilder.

```
Observable<QuerySnapshot> firstList = Firestore.instance.collection(bla).snapshots();

Observable<QuerySnapshot> secondList = Firestore.instance.collection(blabla).snapshots();

Observable<QuerySnapshot> thirdList= Firestore.instance.collection(blablabla).snapshots();

Observable<QuerySnapshot> fourthList= Firestore.instance.collection(blablablabla).snapshots();
```

**LATEST EDIT**
I've changed from Observable to Stream like it was before I've tried using rxdart.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> firstList = Firestore.instance.collection(bla).snapshots();

Stream<QuerySnapshot> secondList = Firestore.instance.collection(blabla).snapshots();

Stream<QuerySnapshot> thirdList= Firestore.instance.collection(blablabla).snapshots();

Stream<QuerySnapshot> fourthList= Firestore.instance.collection(blablablabla).snapshots();
```

And I'm using rxdart to combine them:

```
Observable<SomeList> allList = Observable.combineLatest4(
        firstList,
        secondList,
        thirdList,
        fourthList, (a, b, c, d) => SomeList(a, b, c, d));
```

Here is the class I'm using above:

```
class SomeList{
  QuerySnapshot firstList;
  QuerySnapshot secondList;
  QuerySnapshot thirdList;
  QuerySnapshot fourthList;

  SomeList(this.firstList, this.secondList, this.thirdList,
      this.fourthList);
}
```

Inside the build method I'm returning a StreamBuilder as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: _bla(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                return new StreamBuilder(
                    stream: allList, // here is my main issue
                    ...
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        ),  
    );
}
```

When I run the code I get an exception:

```
Class 'SomeList' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'SomeList'
Tried calling: documents
```

```
type '_BroadcastStream<QuerySnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'Observable<QuerySnapshot>'
```

So I tried to remove the calling of asBroadcastStream() when initializing allList, but the error is the same.

I've looked into these examples before posting my issue:
[Update streams based on filters in Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930918/update-streams-based-on-filters-in-dart-flutter/51931169#51931169) 
[Merge Firestore streams using rxDart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238875/merge-firestore-streams-using-rxdart) 
https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxdart-magical-transformations-of-streams/ 
https://medium.com/@ayushpguptaapg/using-streams-in-flutter-62fed41662e4

What is the proper way to combine these streams into a single stream, and then be used in a StreamBuilder?
Could you please give a small example?

Thank you!

Comment: i am confused: did you get `"is not a subtype of type 'Observable<QuerySnapshot>"` error or not?

Comment: I got this error when I used allList.asBroadcastStream() in StreamBuilder. I removed asBroadcastStream() and now I'm getting a new exception.

Comment: whats the stacktrace then? top 8-10 frames?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to get "documents" field from SomeList instance, which is your class that doesn't have such a field.

Answer (score 0):

*snapshots()* returns simple dart async *Stream*, not rxdart's *Observable*. You can create Observable from it just by wrapping it:

```dart
Observable<QuerySnapshot> firstList = Observable(Firestore.instance.collection(bla).snapshots());
```

UPD: Observable extends Stream class and it can be used like any regular Stream.
RxDart doesn't introduce a new API (unlike any other language's implementations). Instead, it is using dart's default async library, which already has classes like [Stream](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html) and [StreamController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html). *Observable* class just extends *Stream* class, so you can use Observable instance instead of default dart Stream (in StreamBuilder, for example). RxDart's Observable can work with default streams, too.

Another error you're getting is because you're trying to access "documents" field from SomeList instance, but your class that doesn't have such a field.

Comment: Before using this I've tried with Stream<QuerySnapshot> and everything worked as expected. Then I tried to combine multiple streams and found rxdart. Here everything is confusing to me.