# How to filter data from backend using bloc future fetch stream?

Tags: flutter

I have this method on bloc

```
fetchProductAttribute(int _prodId) async {
List<ProductAttribute> productAttribute = await _repository.fetchProductAttribute(_prodId).catchError((err) => _fetcher.addError(err));
_fetcher.sink.add(productAttribute);
}
```

This will call repository then rest api to the backend. Now I want to filter this data.

I will modify this but it's not working... How to do this properly?

```
fetchProductAttribute(int _prodId) async {
List<ProductAttribute> productAttribute = await _repository.fetchProductAttribute(_prodId).catchError((err) => _fetcher.addError(err));
for(var c in productAttribute){
  if(c.variant==true){
    _fetcher.sink.add(productAttribute);
  }
}
}
```

All data still coming up...I want only data with variant true to be displayed on screen. How to do this?

I seen one article on how to do filtering on Stream by using StreamSubscription [here](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930918/update-streams-based-on-filters-in-dart-flutter) but this is not what I want. I want to filter out from the earlier part of REST.

Comment: use [Iterable#where](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html)

Comment: @pskink thanks this is new to me...something more functional programming I'll use this method looks better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one comment said, use the `where` operator over the list.

```
fetchProductAttribute(int _prodId) async {
    List<ProductAttribute> productAttribute = await _repository.fetchProductAttribute(_prodId).catchError((err) => _fetcher.addError(err));
    productAttribute = productAttribute.where((c) => c.variant == true).toList()
    _fetcher.sink.add(productAttribute);
}
```

Comment: Is not filtering correctly or the results are not displayed in the widget?

Comment: sorry2 it's working probably the hot reload issue. thanks. now i think even with for loop as on my question should work.

Comment: The problem with your for loop is that you were just entering an if. The original list retrieved from the API was the original. Also, you were adding multiple times to the sink.

Comment: `c => c.variant == true` does it compile? i thought it should be `(c) => c.variant == true`